# Is there a difference between ReplaySubject and BehaviorSubject when only 1 item is emited?

Tags: rx-java

I have a call to DB which emit me 1 item. Is there a difference between `ReplaySubject` and `BehaviorSubject` when only 1 item is emited?

Comment: Have you read their respective JavaDocs? [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) & [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)

Comment: of course I did and as far as I understand them - the answer to the question is yes; so I'm trying to ensure myself I'm right

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc describes them in great detail and I think the following sentence is relevant for your case:

> When this `BehaviorSubject` is terminated via `onError(Throwable)` or `onComplete()`, the last observed item (if any) is cleared and late `Observer`s only receive the respective terminal event.

That is, as long as they are not terminated and received one `onNext` call, they will replay it to `Observer`s the same way.